# Error: Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, react-native-maps

I have upgraded react-native-maps from 0.26.1 to 0.31.1 for a potential crash fix for android build.
As my current project is on react-native version 0.66.5, we aren't unable to upgrade to latest react-native-maps version due to conflicts between react-native-google-maps and react native maps sdk iOS while installing the pods.

Below is the configuration I have updated for react-native-maps pods spec and react-native-google-places to suffice our react native version.

```
node_modules
 --> react-native-google-places
  --> react-native-google-places.podspec : 
      --> s.dependency 'GoogleMaps', '~>3.5.0'
      --> s.dependency 'GoogleMaps', '~>3.5.0'

node_modules
 --> react-native-maps
  --> react-native-google-maps.podspec : 
      --> s.dependency 'GoogleMaps', '~>3.5.0'
      --> s.dependency 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '4.1.0'
```

and my pod install started working fine, I have applied patches for these two rpm packages and I was able to build the iOS App. But my android application isn't getting build from my Jenkins job after doing the above changes.

app/android/build.gradle:

```
 ext {

    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    // supportLibVersion = "31.0.0"
    // firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
    // playServicesVersion = "18.0.0"
    // androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+" // not required for react-native-maps 0.31.1
}
```

app/android/app/build.gradle:

```
 implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'
```

Below is the error I'm getting while generating the Android build from Jenkins.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (34) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
> Dependency: androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0-beta01.
> AAR metadata file: /Users/knares16/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f5f728c205f8a62980983f37c612be0f/transformed/browser-1.6.0-beta01/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated. Thank you.